# Using Or Clause in PostgreSQL to search for a specific record

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a search record scenario in my module. I have been using Or clause with PostgreSQL . The scenario is that I have 7-8 fields in my module. I want to search for the product from the details given in the fields. My python code is below:

```
cr.execute("select pt.id,pt.name from product_template pt inner join product_product pp on pt.id=pp.id where (pp.radio_phone ='"+str(radio_phone)+"' or pp.person_phone = '"+str(person_phone)+"' or pp.phone_num_phone='"+str(phone_num_phone)+"')")
```

Now I want to search from any of the fields.Like if I enter details on 1 field,I get the matching records . But the problem here is when I try to give different product details in 2 fields, the result is both the 2 fields. All I want is the matching record of 1 product.Means if we give different record details, then the search result should be empty as the details are of two different products. I am using *Or Clause* because I want to search on single field also which is not possible with *and Clause* . I was thinking to include an if statement to check that the details entered are of same product_id. Please guide me if I m doing anything wrong or point me to right direction if my logic is correct. Thanks

Comment: So you're not using and because only one of the variables may be filled and the other empty?

Comment: because there will be situations when I want to search with only 1 field or some times with 2 fields, then how could I use "and" here

Comment: Look into Postgres' full text search.

Comment: You just have to glue the query together with only the fields you want. It's called dynamic SQL and is the standard method of handling searching.

Comment: this is an onchange method associated with the fields. I have no idea of standard searching  Can you elaborate plz

Answer (score 0):

What about using `and` and `like` operators?

```
cr.execute("select pt.id,pt.name from product_template pt inner join product_product pp on pt.id=pp.id where (pp.radio_phone like'%"+str(radio_phone)+"' and pp.person_phone like '%"+str(person_phone)+"' and pp.phone_num_phone like '%"+str(phone_num_phone)+"')")
```

Comment: Have mentioned why am not using 'and'

Comment: Yes, but I proposed to use `and` together with `like '%'` instead of `=` which  can be a solution for you.